# How to slice for loop correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to reverse a for loop such that it stops at a certain value the user inputted.

For example, if there is a list `Hello = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`
and the user inputs a 5
is there a way to get the output

4

5

6

7

8

I've tried

```
user_input = str(input(''))


for i in range(user_input):

   print(Hello[-i -1])
```

and for example I input 5,

I get the output

8

7

6

5

4

Comment: Try: convert the input to integer, find the index of the element in list, then slice the list.

Comment: So do you want `[8, 7, 6, 5,4]` or `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`?

Comment: How exactly is `4, 5, 6, 7, 8` connected to the input `5`? Do you want to print the last 5 numbers? What do you mean by `break`?

Comment: The title is misleading. This is about slicing, not reversing.

Comment: What to return for user_input = 9?

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple way:

```
user_input = int(input())

Hello = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(Hello[-user_input:])
```

> output:
>
> `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

If you want every number to be printed on its own line, you can do it like this:

```
user_input = int(input())

Hello = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(*Hello[-user_input:], sep='\n')
```

> output:
>
> ```
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> ```

Comment: when i print(hello[-user_input:], sep='\n') i still get [4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: @BobKim you forgot the `*` in `print(*hello...` it is used to unpack the list to the print function. You can read more about unpacking lists/tuples with a simple google search :)

Comment: @BobKim btw, feel free to mark my answer as acceped if you feel like it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using python slicing, and index method.

index() method finds the given element in a list and returns its position.

**code:**

```
hello = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i = int(input('enter number: '))

if i in hello and hello.index(i) > 0:
    print(l[hello.index(i)-1:])

else:
    print('cant do this')
```

**note:**

you should check if the element exist in the list or warp your statement with try: except, else you would get ValueError if user enter number not in the list.

you should also implement what to do if user enters the first element in the list or you would get unexpected value.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you need to find an index of the input value in the list and slice the list from one value before the index to the end:

```
start = Hello.index(user_input) - 1
print(Hello[start:])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse your list, you can use `list.reverse()`. 
And so that the code does what you mentioned, you could use this code:

```
Hello = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a = int(input("Please input your number: "))
if a <= len(Hello):
    Hello.reverse()
    print(Hello[:a])
else:
    print("The value is too big")
```